# Missing "and" when citing multiple authors using `\citeauthor` (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, citing

Is there a way to get `\citeauthor` use "and" as the separator for the last entry? Currently all entries are separated by ",".

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=nature,
citestyle=numeric-comp,
maxbibnames=50,
sorting=none,
sortcites,
doi=true,
isbn=false,
url=false,
eprint=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{b1,
        author={Auth1 and Auth2},
        title={Title1},
        year={2000},
        publisher={Pub1},
    }
    @book{b2,
        author={Auth2 and Auth3 and Auth4},
        title={Title2},
        year={2000},
        publisher={Pub2},
    }
    @book{b3,
        author={Auth3 and Auth5},
        title={Title3},
        year={2000},
        publisher={Pub3},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \textcite{b1,b2}\\
    \citeauthor{b2,b3}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want instead is something like this (generated using `\citeauthor{b2} and \citeauthor{b3}`). I would prefer not putting the "and" manually.

[image]